# Analog values without Adc STM32

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32

I have a STM32WB55CGU6 where I have all my ADC pins used up and im trying to obtain the battery level using a pin which does not have a ADC (PB6) which is branched as shown in the picture:

[image]

This follows the principle where it will charge and discharge  following this link :
[link](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/08/reading-analogue-sensors-with-one-gpio-pin/?fbclid=IwAR02xk-aHW8xhmssrk5xmvr4oUItz5l7KnuEGclmGBjaDE7tFAA6C1Utqx4)

This is my current program but somehow it doesnt work and im pretty sure im doing something wronf but what I am not too sure.

```
while(1){
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET); 
      HAL_Delay(1);
      HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6);
      while(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6)==1){
          time++;
      }
      if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6)==0){value = time;}
}
```

Im programming with STMCubeIDE where I have set the pin to GPIO_Analog

Comment: jellybean, I formatted the code you posted for you (that was a single click of work). You're experienced enough a user to do that yourself, though.

Comment: basic questions: do you have a separate stabilized supply voltage that you use for VDDA and VDDIO of your STM32?

Comment: @MarcusMüller no its the same supply voltage and thank you for the format

Comment: @Hearth that was my post just that im not sure how to code it on stmcubeIDE

Comment: @jellybean well, then *all* your ADC measurements are relative to your varying battery voltage, and *all* your digital output voltages are relative to the battery voltage, too. So, no, this can't work, in no modification. You might want to try understanding what you're doing!

Comment: I have a buck-boost voltage regulator which ensures that it'll receive 3.3V as an input voltage so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @jellybean I asked **specifically** whether you have a stabilized voltage for VDDA and VDDIO or not.

Comment: @jellybean That message was automatically added when I fllagged this as a duplicate. I liked the old auto-message that just said "possible duplicate of X" better....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the schematics, yours don't match how it is supposed to be connected.

If the PB6 was connected to the resistors directly, and the 10nF were connected from PB6 to ground, it would work. Then, the STM32 can discharge the capacitor, and count time until it has been charged.

Also, if the pin is configured into Analog mode, it's not an output, and both the digital input and output buffers are disabled, so it's digital state cannot be set or read.

Comment: I've actually tried that but seeing that the code doesnt work i tried changing it

Comment: See my edit. The problem might be that it must not be an analog pin. And you never change it between input and output either.

Comment: since im using stmCubeIDE do I have to set it to like for example output pin first then manually change in the code to an input pin?

Comment: It does not matter what you use to code. Yes, you have to change between input and output, unless you make it an open drain pin.